# Custom Sorting In AG-Grid React

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I'm currently trying to create a default sort order for an AG Grid in which rows with certain program types/values are pushed to the top of the table. For example, if program value is green with a value of X then I want those rows first, then rows with program value blue and value of Y, then program value yellow and value of Z, and finally all others. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for: `https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-sorting/#example-custom-sorting-groups`

Basically, you have to create a comparator function inside your column definition. Then provide that column definition to your AgGridReact tag

Comment: Actually I found exactly what I need, it's called postSort, but I'm not sure how to implement it since the data I need to search isn't displayed in the table but rather only exists in the JSON. I'm trying to read and match the JSON data to use postSort but it isn't working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You could use hidden columns to access that JSON data... https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-state/

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing, thank you!